# Synchronize Crosstab column widths with Charts in Jasperreports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, reporting

we've got quite a nerve destroying problem here:
In Jasperreports we have MultiAxisCharts which consist of Line Charts and StackedBar Charts. Underneath these Charts the customer wants us to draw Crosstabs which display the exact digits of the chart above the Crosstab.

Well, Jasperreports doesn't provide a way to synchronize the width of a Crosstab column to the width of a bar in a StackedBar chart. Moreover the width of a Crosstab column in- and decreases with the digit written in its cells.

We display up to 54 (52 weeks per year and 2 additional for misc. information) columns in such a Crosstab.

Does anyone if you have an idea regarding this situation - besides shredding this unholy mess ;)

Comment: what is the minimum number of possible columns in the chart (i.e. is it a year to date based report or a rolling year based report)?

Comment: there is always a fixed number, and there a two seperate reports. one is based on calendar weeks (54 columns) and one on months (14 columns). Two more each, because of a label column and one sum column.